# Get Currently finished Download

Tags: android, android-download-manager

im using DownloadManager to download files in android, and i need to run a command for everydownloaded file, but my receiver is not working, if i put 10files to download, it just return the LAST downloaded file title, why?

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

            long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                    DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setFilterById(enqueue);
            Cursor c = dmAndroid.query(query);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                //Log.d("ainfo", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"))); -> stil return just the last
                /*
                int i = 0;
                 while(i < c.getColumnCount()) { Log.d("ainfo",
                 c.getColumnName(i) + "-" + i + "-" + c.getString(i));
                 i++; }
                */
                int columnIndex = c
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                        .getInt(columnIndex)) {

// if i put here still return the last download only
                    String uriString = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                    if (downloadId == c.getInt(0)) {
                        Log.d("ainfo", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"))); //same, just the last download file title


                    }
                }


            }

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be reasons
Did you register your Broadcast Receiver in android manifest file.
you got any error here post your logcat

Comment: why i need to register it since its working without registering? (i guess), and logcat doesnt return any error, it just download all files correctly and in the folder, but i cant do command for each one cuz i cant get each download.complete =/